# Elegant way to dynamically query firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any elegant way to dynamically add where condition to the query based on conditions? For e.g, the default query is

```
query = collectionReference
.whereField(SaleProperties.saledate.rawValue, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate)
.whereField(SaleProperties.saledate.rawValue, isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDate)
.whereField(SaleProperties.isapprovedbystoremanager.rawValue, isEqualTo: true)
```

and I have 4 different conditions, like, `state, division, store, user`. When these filters is/are selected, I need to add where condition accordingly. Lets assume, I have selected `state` then the query would be

```
query = collectionReference
    .whereField(SaleProperties.state.rawValue, isEqualTo: selectedState)
    .whereField(SaleProperties.saledate.rawValue, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate)
    .whereField(SaleProperties.saledate.rawValue, isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDate)
    .whereField(SaleProperties.isapprovedbystoremanager.rawValue, isEqualTo: true)
```

likewise, if I have selected `state and division`

```
    query = collectionReference
    .whereField(SaleProperties.state.rawValue, isEqualTo: selectedState)
    .whereField(SaleProperties.division.rawValue, isEqualTo: selectedDivision)
    .whereField(SaleProperties.saledate.rawValue, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDate)
    .whereField(SaleProperties.saledate.rawValue, isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDate)                 
   .whereField(SaleProperties.isapprovedbystoremanager.rawValue, isEqualTo: true)
```

Above example is illustrated just for two conditions. Like this, I need to check for 4 different conditions with combination of others.The probability of combination will be like 24 queries. So It would be great if someone knows the elegant way to form the queries.

*********Answer********

With the default query (please see above the default query), I check for the condition, example, if `state`is selected, then I just add one more condition to the default query

```
    if(isStateSelected == true)
    {
   query =  query.whereField(SaleProperties.state.rawValue, isEqualTo: selectedState)
    }
```

likewise, if `division` is selected

```
    if(isDivisionSelected == true)
    {
  query = query.whereField(SaleProperties.division.rawValue, isEqualTo: selectedDivision)
    }
```

so if conditions are true, additional condition will be added to the default query

Comment: So you say that you'll need to query your database based on 24 conditions?

Comment: I do not think you can combine range operators with firebase

Comment: I've marked this as a dup of the JavaScript solution, because they are essentially identical.  But I don't think there is nothing "elegant" about it.  You are basically obliged to re-assign a new Query object every time you want to add another conditional filter to the query using whereField().  Just keep building and assigning until you're done.

Comment: @DougStevenson - Thanks for referring the link. It helped me build the query based on condition.

Comment: @AlexMamo Initially i thought so, but after seeing the doug's reference link, there is no need to for 24 conditions, just 4 is enough

Comment: For those who are looking for same kind of solution, i have updated my question with the answer